# Compatibility Issues in HTML

Tags: html

I have a compatibility issue with my html code, the only browser that works is konquorer, which comes with redhat Linux.

Browsers such as chrome, firefox, and IE(older versions work), will have strange select/option tables.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <TITLE>StripCal Python Wrapper</TITLE>
    </head>


    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            width: 500px;
            clear: both;
        }
        .container input{
            width: 500px;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>


    <body>
    <p>
        Input StripCal Field Inputs:
    </p>

    <p>
        <form action="StripCalPythonRun.py" method="post">


                <TABLE BORDER=1>
                <TR>
                    <TD> Configuration of the trace(s): </TD>
                    <TD> The Trace is Composed of: </TD>
                    <TD> Dimensions are in: </TD>
                    <TD> Output SPice Format: </TD>
                    <TD> When Ready: </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                    <CENTER>
                    <select name="config" size=10>
                            <option value="1" selected="selected">One_Stripline</option>
                            <option value="2">One_Microstrip</option>
                            <option value="3">Two_Stripline</option>
                            <option value="4">Two_Stripline_Pairs</option>
                            <option value="5">Two_Microstrip</option>
                            <option value="6">Two_Microstrip_Pairs</option>
                            <option value="7">Stripline_Array</option>
                            <option value="8">Stripline_Pair_Array</option>
                            <option value="9">Microstrip_Array</option>
                            <option value="10">Microstrip_Pair_Array</option>
                        </select>
                    </CENTER>
                    </TD>
                <TD>
                <CENTER>
                    <select name="COND" size=10>
                        <option value="Bulk_Copper" selected="selected">Bulk_Copper</option>
                        <option value="Plated_Copper">Plated_Copper</option>
                        <option value="Sputtered_Copper">Sputtered_Copper</option>
                        <option value="Tungsten">Tungsten</option>
                        <option value="Aluminum">Aluminum</option>
                        <option value="Nickel">Nickel</option>
                        <option value="Cofired_Tungsten">Cofired_Tungsten</option>
                        <option value="IBM_Moly">IBM_Moly</option>
                        <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </CENTER>
                </TD>

                <TD>
                <CENTER>
                    <select name="dimen" size=2>
                        <option value="MILS">MILS</option>
                        <option value="uM" selected="selected">Microns</option>
                    </select>
                </CENTER>
                </TD>

                <TD>
                <CENTER>
                    <select name="spicever" size=3>
                        <option value="HPSPICE">HPSPICE</option>
                        <option value="HSPICE" selected="selected">HSPICE</option>
                        <option value="SPECTRE">SPECTRE</option>
                    </select>
                </CENTER>
                </TD>

                <TD>
                <CENTER>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Input_Type" value="list">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute">
                </CENTER>
                </TD>

                </TR>
                </TABLE>

                <TABLE BORDER=1>
                    <TR>
                        <TD> Subcircuit path: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="SBCKPATH" value="tmp1"> </TD>
                        <TD> Transmission line call name: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="TLNAME" value="test1"> </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>

                <TABLE BORDER=1>
                    <TR>
                        <TD> Trace width: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="W9" value="24"> </TD>
                        <TD> Dielectric thickness ABOVE trace: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="B19" value="33"> </TD>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                        <TD> Trace Length (in in/cm): </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="length" value="1"> </TD>
                        <TD> Dielectric Thickness BELOW trace: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="B29" value="33"> </TD>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                        <TD> Trace Thickness: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="T9" value="15"> </TD>
                        <TD> Gap Between Adjacent Traces: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="GAP9" value="1000"> </TD>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                        <TD> Resistivity ("Rho") (Ohm-meter): </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="rho"> </TD>
                        <TD> Gap Between Adjacent Pairs: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="GAP99" value="1000"> </TD>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                        <TD> Dielectric Loss Tangent: </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="delta" value="0.01"> </TD>
                        <TD> Dielectric's Relative Permittivity ("er"): </TD>
                        <TD> <input type="text" name="Er" value="3.35"> </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </form>
```

Other Page:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
            <TITLE>StripCal Python Wrapper</TITLE>
        </head>


        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
                width: 500px;
                clear: both;
            }
            .container input{
                width: 500px;
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>


        <body>
        <p>
            Input StripCal Field Inputs:
        </p>

        <p>
            <form action="StripCalPythonRun.py" method="post">


                    <TABLE BORDER=1>
                    <TR>
                        <TD> Configuration of the trace(s): </TD>
                        <TD> The Trace is Composed of: </TD>
                        <TD> Dimensions are in: </TD>
                        <TD> Output Spice Format: </TD>
                        <TD> When Ready: </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                        <CENTER>

                            <select name="config" size=10 >
                            <option value="1" selected="selected">One_Stripline</option>
                            <option value="2">One_Microstrip</option>
                            <option value="3">Two_Stripline</option>
                            <option value="4">Two_Stripline_Pairs</option>
                            <option value="5">Two_Microstrip</option>
                            <option value="6">Two_Microstrip_Pairs</option>
                            <option value="7">Stripline_Array</option>
                            <option value="8">Stripline_Pair_Array</option>
                            <option value="9">Microstrip_Array</option>
                            <option value="10">Microstrip_Pair_Array</option>
                        </select>


                        </CENTER>
                        </TD>
                    <TD>
                    <CENTER>

                        <select name="COND" size=10>
                        <select name="COND" size=10>
                            <option value="Bulk_Copper" selected="selected">Bulk_Copper</option>
                            <option value="Plated_Copper">Plated_Copper</option>
                            <option value="Sputtered_Copper">Sputtered_Copper</option>
                            <option value="Tungsten">Tungsten</option>
                            <option value="Aluminum">Aluminum</option>
                            <option value="Nickel">Nickel</option>
                            <option value="Cofired_Tungsten">Cofired_Tungsten</option>
                            <option value="IBM_Moly">IBM_Moly</option>
                            <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>


                    </CENTER>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <CENTER>

                        <select name="dimen" size=2>
                        <select name="dimen" size=2>
                            <option value="MILS">MILS</option>
                            <option value="uM" selected="selected">Microns</option>
                        </select>


                    </CENTER>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <CENTER>

                        <select name="spicever" size=3>
                        <select name="spicever" size=3>
                            <option value="HPSPICE">HPSPICE</option>
                            <option value="HSPICE" selected="selected">HSPICE</option>
                            <option value="SPECTRE">SPECTRE</option>
                        </select>


                    </CENTER>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <CENTER>

                    <input type="hidden" name="Input_Type" value="list">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute">


                    </CENTER>
                    </TD>

                    </TR>
                    </TABLE>


                    <TABLE BORDER=1>
                        <TR>


                            <TD> Subcircuit path </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="SBCKPATH" value=tmp1></TD>
                            <TD> Transmission line call name </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="TLNAME" value=test1></TD>

                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>


                    <TABLE BORDER=1>
                        <TR>


                            <TD> Trace width: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="W9" value=24></TD>

                            <TD> Dielectric thickness ABOVE trace: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="B19" value=33></TD>

                        </TR>

                        <TR>


                            <TD> Trace Length (in in/cm): </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="length" value=1></TD>

                            <TD> Dielectric Thickness BELOW trace: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="B29" value=33></TD>

                        </TR>

                        <TR>


                            <TD> Trace Thickness: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="T9" value=15></TD>

                            <TD> Gap Between Adjacent Traces: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="GAP9" value=1000></TD>

                        </TR>

                        <TR>


                            <TD> Resistivity ("Rho") (Ohm-meter): </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="rho" value=rho_empty></TD>

                            <TD> Gap Between Adjacent Pairs: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="GAP99" value=1000></TD>

                        </TR>

                        <TR>


                            <TD> Dielectric Loss Tangent: </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="delta" value=0.01></TD>

                            <TD> Dielectric's Relative Permittivity("er"): </TD>
                            <TD> <input type="text" name="Er" value=3.35></TD>

                        </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I view this code and pressed compute (goes to another page with the same table), the select options get messed up.

Original Table:
[image]
Table after "Compute" was clicked:
[image]

I've also tried to set content to emulate IE7, but it does not solve the problem. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Edit:
- Added closing /Html tag
- Added Opening Body and Closing Body

Tried to removed center tag, however, it did not work

Comment: You don't have a `<body>` tag. Throw your content in one. Also, your `<html>` tag is never closed.

Comment: My guess, and this is indeed a guess, is that the deprecated `<center>` tags are causing problems.

Comment: I removed <center> tags, however, it still have this problem.

Comment: The problem is on the “other page”, which is not described at all in the question.

Comment: Added the other page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look through your code on the second page you posted, there are 3 different select fields that have duplicate `<select>` tags that open the select form tag twice. Here is a snippet of the code you posted:

```
<select name="spicever"  size=3>
<select name="spicever" size=3>
                            <option value="HPSPICE">HPSPICE</option>
                            <option value="HSPICE" selected="selected">HSPICE</option>
                            <option value="SPECTRE">SPECTRE</option>
</select>
```

I suggest you remove the duplicate code and it should display correctly.

Comment: +1, I think this is the problem. We clearly see them with the edit I made to fix the indents.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. When the code is rendered on the page the select tag is closing prematurely which is causing the <option> data to be displayed as normal text on the page. This is exactly what his screenshot is showing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Somehow I did not catch this issue. Somehow konquorer did not have this error.